# Why ascending argument of rank method does not work?

Tags: python, pandas, series, rank

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[30,40,10,20]})
df['rank'] = df['b'].rank()
```

works as expected.

```
df['rank'] = df['b'].rank(ascending=True)
```

generates:

```
TypeError: rank() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ascending'
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? Works for me (tested with pandas 0.11)

Answer (score 1):

The `ascending` argument to [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) was [introduced in 0.7.2](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/release.html#pandas-0-7-2). I recommend upgrading to the [stable version](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) (currently 0.12), for the latest bug-fixes and features (like this).

*Note: if you are using an older version of pandas it's usually a good idea to look at the online docs for that specific version (see [right hand side of webpage](http://pandas.pydata.org/)), as well as the help in your interpreter.*